# How to split a string with the character "[" using split() in java

Tags: java, string, split

I am not able to give "[" directly as it considers it as char set. If i try giving "[" 
, i get a error saying escape sequence is not possible for "[".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape it with a double backslash:

```
\\[
```

This is needed to stop the regex engine treating the `[` as the start of a character class.

The first backslash is needed since the `\\[` is part of a string literal; only the second backslash will make it to the regex engine. In other words, the regex engine will see the above as `\[`.

Comment: It works!! Thanks!! but can u explain how?? bcoz "\ [" looks valid too.

Comment: @kamaraj6990: No, `"\ ["` isn't even a valid string literal - and you don't want to use a space in your split expression anyway.

Comment: No no i didn mean space here!! This website is reading "{slash}{sq parenthesis}" as "{sq parenthesis}". so i left a space.

Comment: The regex requires one backslash, but since this is a Java string literal that backslash needs to be backslash escaped too.  Hence `"\\["`.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split( src, '[' )

Done.  Why are you wasting time on this?